# Use Springfox Swagger-UI and it's not working, what am I missing?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a new spring boot 2.7.4 project with these dependencies in the pom.xml and I added the necessary dependencies for swagger here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>societe-person</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>societe-person</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project-base-package>com.example.societepersonnel</project-base-package>
    <start-class>com.example.societepersonnel.SocietePersonnelApplication</start-class>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2021.2.3</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-schema</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/open-api/openapi-spec.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>${project-base-package}</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>${project-base-package}.dto</modelPackage>
                        <invokerPackage>${project-base-package}.swagger</invokerPackage>
                        <skipValidateSpec>false</skipValidateSpec>
                        <strictSpec>true</strictSpec>
                        <importMappings>Problem=org.zalando.problem.Problem</importMappings>
                        <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/.openapi-spec-generator-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                        <configOptions>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <configPackage>${project-base-package}.swagger</configPackage>
                            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                            <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Builder @lombok.Data @lombok.NoArgsConstructor
                                @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
                            </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                        </configOptions>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

AddressController like this

```
package com.example.societepersonnel.domain.address;

import com.example.societepersonnel.AddressesApiDelegate;
import com.example.societepersonnel.dto.AddressDto;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class AddressController implements AddressesApiDelegate {

private final AddressService addressService;

public AddressController(AddressService addressService) {
    this.addressService = addressService;

}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<AddressDto> createAddress(AddressDto addressDto) {
    AddressDto dto = addressService.createAddress(addressDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAddress(Long id) {
    addressService.deleteAddress(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<AddressDto> findAddressById(Long id) {
    AddressDto addressDto = addressService.findAddressById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(addressDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<AddressDto>> findAddresses() {
    List<AddressDto> dtoList = addressService.listAddressDto();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dtoList, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<AddressDto> updateAddress(Long id, AddressDto addressDto) {
    AddressDto dto = addressService.updateAddress(id, addressDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
 }
}
```

EnterpriseController like this

```
package com.example.societepersonnel.domain.enterprise;

import com.example.societepersonnel.EnterprisesApiDelegate;
import com.example.societepersonnel.dto.EnterpriseDto;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class EnterpriseController implements EnterprisesApiDelegate {

private final EnterpriseService enterpriseService;


public EnterpriseController(EnterpriseService enterpriseService) {
    this.enterpriseService = enterpriseService;
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<EnterpriseDto> createEnterprise(EnterpriseDto enterpriseDto) {
    EnterpriseDto dto = enterpriseService.createEnterprise(enterpriseDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteEnterprise(Long id) {
    enterpriseService.deleteEnterprise(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<EnterpriseDto> findEnterpriseById(Long id) {
    EnterpriseDto dto = enterpriseService.findEnterpriseById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<EnterpriseDto>> findEnterprises() {
    List<EnterpriseDto> dtos = enterpriseService.findEnterprises();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dtos, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<EnterpriseDto> updateEnterprise(Long id, EnterpriseDto enterpriseDto) {
    EnterpriseDto dto = enterpriseService.updateEnterprise(id, enterpriseDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

PersonController like this

```
package com.example.societepersonnel.domain.person;

import com.example.societepersonnel.PersonsApiDelegate;
import com.example.societepersonnel.dto.PersonDto;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PersonController implements PersonsApiDelegate {

private final PersonService personService;

public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
    this.personService = personService;
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> createPerson(PersonDto personDto) {
    PersonDto dto = personService.createPerson(personDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> deletePerson(Long id) {
    personService.deletePerson(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonDto>> findAllPersons() {
    List<PersonDto> personDtos = personService.findPersons();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(personDtos);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> findPersonById(Long id) {
    PersonDto dto = personService.findPersonById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(dto);
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> updatePerson(Long id, PersonDto personDto) {
    PersonDto dto = personService.updatePerson(id, personDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

[image]

And in the browser display this image

[image]

And I have the code of the main program is the following

```
package com.example.societepersonnel;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class SocietePersonnelApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SocietePersonnelApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

And the SwaggerConfig configuration file is as follows

```
package com.example.societepersonnel.core.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo; 
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    String groupName = "Swagger";
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(getApiInfo())
            .groupName(groupName)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build().
            pathMapping("/")
            .enableUrlTemplating(false);
}

private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {

    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Swagger API Doc")
            .description("More description about the API")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .build();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

}
```

All that is necessary for the configuration is already here.
I don't know if I've missed something that the swagger doesn't display in the browser.
Please help me. :)

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see in Swagger UI that is not there? Your screenshot shows a properly functional Swagger UI.

Comment: Also, why do you have both Springfox and Springdoc as dependencies? They are sort of mutually exclusive.

Comment: I would like to see in the swagger interface the different path that I have already put in the controllers like for my examples
 
address-controller

GET/addresses
POST/addresses
....

enterprise-controller

GET/enterprises
POST/enterprises

Comment: For the dependencies are all obligatory and if I eliminate an independence it will have an error in the execution